# Convert strings to variable name in Netlogo

Tags: string, variables, foreach, set, netlogo

I was trying to update a bunch of global variables using the `set` command.

The global variables are the combinations of different strings.

For example, I have 6 global variables called:

`a_x, b_x, c_x, a_y, b_y, c_y`

I want to update the values of all six global variables into 1 using the `foreach` command.

Below is my code:

```
let a_x 0
let b_x 0
let c_x 0
let a_y 0
let b_y 0
let c_y 0

let first_list (list "a" "b" "c")
let second_list (list "x" "y")

foreach first_list [
   [i] -> 
   foreach second_list [
     [j] -> 
   set (word i "_" j) 1
 ]
]
```

I got the "This isn't something you can use "set" on" error message.

I guess I may need to convert the strings `(word i "_" j)` into a variable name so that the Netlogo can update it by the `set` command.

Is there any way that I can convert the strings into a variable name in the `foreach` loop in Netlogo?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `run` primitive](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#run) on a string to execute NetLogo code that you build from strings.  You can use that to `set` global variables.  Instead of constructing just the variable name with `word`, you can construct the whole `set a_x 1` statement, then `run` that.

This does not work with local `let` variables, however, due to the way `run` handles scope when used with string values.

So here is your sample updated with globals that will work:

```
globals [
  a_x
  b_x 
  c_x
  a_y
  b_y
  c_y
]

to test
  clear-globals ; reset to `0`
  
  let first_list (list "a" "b" "c")
  let second_list (list "x" "y")

  foreach first_list [
    [i] -> foreach second_list [
      [j] -> 
        let t (word "set " i "_" j " " 1)
        show t
        run t
    ]
  ]
  
  show a_x ; outputs `1`
end
```

Edit to add a second option.

You can also use [the `table` extension](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/table.html) instead to store the values.  It can use strings as keys (your variable names), and store whatever values you like.  Depending on your use case, this might overall wind up easier/simpler.

Comment: Hey @Jasper, I was wondering, why do you write it like ```run (word "set " i "_" j " " 1)``` instead of ```run (word "set i_j 1")```? It does not read ```i``` and ```j```as variables like that?

Comment: @Pol So `i` and `j` are the values from `first_list` and `second_list`, so the `(word "set " i "_" j " " 1)` will make a string like `"set a_x 1"`.  If you just put the `i_j` inside the string, they won't be interpreted as variable names as desired.  Maybe swapping the code to be `let t (word "set " i "_" j " " 1) show t run t` would help it make more sense, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see, putting them all inside the ```" "``` would result in reading ```i``` and ```j``` as the actual characters, not the value of the variable they store. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do that. You are trying to treat a string holding the name of a variable as the variable, which does not work.

Perhaps the closest you can get is this, assuming a_x b_x c_x ... are **already defined** as global or local variables:

```
 let list-of-variables (list
   a_x
   b_x
   c_x
   ... )

 foreach list-of-variables [ next-variable -> set next-variable 1 ]
```